# Controller's scope is undefined after compiling a directive with $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm writing an unit test for this directive:

```
.directive('readOnlyExplorer', () => ({
  templateUrl:
    'components/experiment-explorer/read-only-explorer.template.html',
  restrict: 'E',
  controller: 'ReadOnlyExplorerController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  scope: {
    extensionRegExp: '@?',
    foldersRegExp: '@?',
  },
  bindToController: true
}))
```

As you can see, I'm using controllerAs and an isolate scope to pass arguments to the directive. The controller is class based.

Everything works except for unit test. What I'm doing is to compile the directive and then trying to access the scope. This is the code of the unit test:

```
element = $compile(
  '<read-only-explorer extension-reg-exp="csv" folders-reg-exp="csv"></read-only-explorer>')($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
const controller = element.scope().vm;
console.log(controller.foldersRegExp) // isolate scope variable, it is undefined
console.log(controller.loadFolder) // controller method, it is undefined
```

The problem is that neither `scope()` nor `vm` contain the scope I want to access. `vm` is actually undefined. Why is this happening? I guess I'm not using `$compile` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is on the isolate scope of the element:<sup>[1](https://plnkr.co/edit/7yYrra86UA0nyK0lNwmB?p=preview)</sup>

```
element = $compile(
  '<read-only-explorer extension-reg-exp="csv" folders-reg-exp="csv"></read-only-explorer>')($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
̶c̶o̶n̶s̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶(̶)̶.̶v̶m̶;̶
const controller = element.isolateScope().vm;
console.log(controller.foldersRegExp) // isolate scope variable
console.log(controller.loadFolder) // controller method
```